# The header is scrolling in the page, when clicking the content second time?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, header, scroll

In my page i have a header and and a listview in the container area,
when scrolling the first time the header is in its position, but after clicking in the content  ,i scrolled the header is moving.
I put data-position is fixed in the container tag.
What will be the problem?

```
<div data-role="page">

            <div id="page1">

                <div data-theme="b" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                     <h2 id="doc_title">
                 </h2>
               </div>


                <div data-role="content" style="position: inherit; margin-top:1.8em" data-theme="d">    
                    <ul id="cat_hold" data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true" style.marginTop="1.5em">               
                    </ul>
              </div>


            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try combining your top two `<div>` elements. The `data-role="header"` and `data-role="content"` should be direct descendants of your `data-role="page"` element.

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    ...
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">    
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed Headers just work fine for iOS-Devices. Implement iScrollview to achieve a more stable performance. https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview